# IE8 crashing on page load, debugger says nothing

Tags: jquery, debugging, internet-explorer-8

The report I get is that all browsers work just fine on this site (link below), except IE8.  I tested IE8, and it does crash on each new page load, then it reloads the tab and shows the page.  When I use the built in debugger, it simply crashes and restarts the tab, which turns debugging off.

If I put IE8 in compatibility mode, it works fine.  I turned on the debugger in compat mode and I don't get any errors.  The only console message that comes up is "LOG: [cycle] terminating; zero elements found be selector", which I doubt is a problem.

I did not develop this site, so I'm not really familiar with the JS code it's running, but it appears to be mostly jQuery and a plugin called jsDatePick.  There is also a swfobject.js, and it's using cufon.

I don't expect anyone to do massive debugging on my behalf, I can take care of that.  I was just hoping that someone might have come across a similar issue and might be able to pinpoint it quickly or at least point me in the first places to look before I start removing js includes one at a time.

[link removed]

Comment: One thing that can crash some versions of IE is if the JS code tries to manipulate the DOM (add/remove elements) before the page is done loading.

Comment: Check out if any css/js is being minified. I know IE8 can have some issues with this, especially if the css/js was malformed to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Narrowed down the answer:

`wp_enqueue_script()` was not being used to include jQuery in the WordPress header file.  Instead, jQuery was being included manually.  Then, when a lightbox WordPress plugin needed jQuery, since enqueue had not been used, it created a second script include for jQuery.  This was apparently too difficult for IE to handle.

Anyway, removing the second script include for jQuery fixed the problem on my local machine.  So, I'll assume that's the answer.

Comment: re missing DOCTYPE - that won't cause IE to crash but it will cause IE to go into quirksmode, which can cause horrible page layout issues. The only excuse for a missing doctype is if it's very old code which never had it in the first place. If this is new code and your dev missed out the doctype, then it's a really bad sign.

Comment: I think it's a lack of familiarity with WordPress or the theme itself that was downloaded didn't have it.  I'm guessing lack of familiarity with WordPress, which also explains not using enqueue.  It's definitely an understandable mistake for those who haven't customized WP much.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while using IE7 and IE8 on a website I developed a while ago.

The problem was related with using `position:relative;` on an element. I know this is a long shot actually and probably not related, but it might give you a starting point.

Best thing to do, to know what might be wrong, is cloning the website to a local or offsite location and start chopping code. IE8 is not that good when it comes to debugging and might point you a code line completely unrelated to the actual error.

As soon as you find the code portion responsable for the error it's just a matter of time until you can find the actual culprit.

Comment: Yeah, if one of my 3 items in my self-answer don't answer it, the clipping process is my next step...I just hate doing that, it's a PITA.  IE7 or IE8, I recall would always crash if someone put a comma after the last item in an object declaration var i = { item:1,item2, }.  P.S. Debugging in IE8+ is much better now, breakpoints, right line #, etc.: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2008/03/13/jscript-debugger-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx